# Can someone explain the detailed technical workflow for communication between elastic agent and fleet server

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, agent, elastic-beats

Need a deeper understanding of how authentication workflow is implemented during the first time installation of elastic agent and how the communication of elastic agent with the fleet server is organized.

1. Which communication protocol is used (GRPC/Web Sockets/WebHooks) and why?
2. How service token helps to authenticate users? is service token require for every time whenever elastic agent tries to reach the fleet server?

So I have gone through the publicly available docs but need a detailed analysis on this.

Comment: Reg 2, first question. It would be easier for someone to address for exact doubt, if you can present your understanding and the references you have been through to acquire it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.